# jQuery parseJSON issue/bug?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, google-chrome

I had a larger problem and narrowed it down to this.

$.parseJSON() is not properly parsing JSON returned from my server.

I believe it has something to do with similar schema (I'm not sure if that's the right term for javascript objects). Does anyone know what's going on here or is this a bug?

document.ready:

```
$.ajax(
        {
            url: "MyProjects.aspx/initjson",
            success: function (msg) {
                j = $.parseJSON(msg.d);
                console.log(msg.d);
                console.log(j);
            }
        }
);
```

Produces this:
[image: Screenshot Of Chrome Console]
**Note that the 2 objects in *sections* are the different before being parsed, but the same afterwards.**

When I change the fieldnames it works though:
[image: Screenshot 2 of Chrome Console]

- jQuery 1.6.4 & 1.7.1
- User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2
- Server:ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
- X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319

Comment: AFAIK it is parsing correctly, which part are you referring to?

Comment: The sectionids in "sections" are 2 and 1 before but 1 and 1 after

Comment: Could you include the response in text format so I can copy it?

Comment: `$.parseJSON()` is parsing correctly. http://jsfiddle.net/QbFhx/

Comment: It works fine when I copy text output and use jsfiddle, there is something specific about this case (which makes it all the more fun to deal with)

Comment: Why are you parsing msg.d instead of the full msg which is the actual response from the server? Did you try using the native JSON.parse() instead? I tested it using the JSON string `"var msg = '{"sections" : [{"sectionid" : "2"}, {"sectionid" : "1"}], "projects" : [{"sectionid" : "1"}, {"sectionid" : "1"}]}';"` and it worked just great

Comment: @devnull69. asp.net returns this kind of json object when using page methods: `{ d: {... < what you return from your method > ...}}`. He's doing right.

Comment: and regardless of the type of server, the parsed object doesn't match the json

Comment: Have you tried giving different names for array items (sectionid and projectsectionid for inst.) ?

Comment: When I give them different names it works correctly screenshot: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3115379/jquery_parsejson_bug2.PNG

Comment: I don't see a problem when I try it with jQuery 1.7.1 (which you noted you are using).  Though I should mention your integers should not be in quotes.  `{"sectionid" : 2}`  Also you may want to specify the content-type in the AJAX call (not sure if you are and just omitted it for this question)

Comment: Yep, no repro for me on jsfiddle.net, typed it in manually myself.  This works just like the 2nd sample on 1.7.1 and 1.6.4

Comment: @TerryR That's all handled with `$.ajaxSetup({
                type: "POST",
                data: "{}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                async: true,
                cache: false,
                error: function (x, e) {
                    alert("The call to the server side failed. " + x.responseText);
                }
            });`

Comment: What happens when you return just msg.d from the server directly, and skip the parseJSON() call altogether?

Comment: Could you print "Network->Response" screen?

Answer (score -1):

I believe that the parsing is correct.  In your first console.log call you will notice that the order of the objects is sections then projects but when you call console.log on the json object, j, it is returning them in the opposite order but the sectionid values are still correct for each object.

Comment: I believe `console.log()` spits stuff out in alphabetical order. This is not an answer, nor does it provide any helpful insight.